# Did Foursquare just pulled the specials object from the venues list?

Tags: api, foursquare

Earlier today I was able to get the "specials" object inside the full venues object. Now it appears that is one (and therefor breaking a part of my app) yet I am using versioned api from them past the "init date" (mine is 20120813).

Is this coincidence today or should I expect more things to break?

Thanks

Comment: Which endpoint are you hitting that's missing the specials detail?

Comment: im doing the 'venues/search' endpoint was working great for weeks and then puff no more specials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report! This is a bug on our end, which should be fixed shortly. In the meantime, you can assume that venues without specials included have no specials (the specials object is missing because there are none).